# Error in displaying image using streamlit (st.image)

Tags: python, python-requests, streamlit

So, I am trying to scrape images from the web,and display the same to the user.
The function that I have used to do the same is below:

```
import base64
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from io import BytesIO
import requests
from PIL import Image
import streamlit as st

def new_img(txt):
    response = requests.get("https://source.unsplash.com/random{0}".format(txt))
    bites = BytesIO(base64.b64decode(response.content))
    aux_im = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
    st.image(aux_im)
```

The issue is, the images are getting displayed as:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHXvl.png)

I initially thought there is some issue with the get request, but when I run the same command in jupyter notebook using aux_im.show(), the relevant image gets displayed. I wanted to use matplotlib but apparently the functionality of imshow() has not been added to the framework yet Does anyone have an idea as to why it is happening?

Answer (score 0):

It worked by removing the function parameter and calling the function with the URL with no parameter :

```py
import base64
from io import BytesIO
import requests
import streamlit as st
from PIL import Image

def new_img():
    response = requests.get("https://source.unsplash.com/random")
    bites = BytesIO(base64.b64decode(response.content))
    aux_im = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
    st.image(aux_im)

new_img()
```

Comment: Yes it works without the parameter. But the thing is I want to retrieve a picture of the entity passed as the parameter

Comment: Then it is your URL that is probably wrong, take a look [here](https://awik.io/generate-random-images-unsplash-without-using-api/) for some examples.